# Login com PHP usando PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Já sei fazer cadastros, porém login é meio complicado para mim. Encontrei uns materiais na internet e gostaria de saber o que a linha a seguir faz. Sei que estou coletando as informações do form, queria saber o que faz especificamente `"  ? $_POST['password'] : ''; "` essa parte da linha em diante.

```
// resgata variáveis do formulário
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é o que chamamos de um `if` ternário. O que vem depois da atribuição (`=`) e antes da `?` é uma condição para que seja atribuido o que vem antes ou depois de `:`.

```
? == if
: == else
```

Em um exemplo prático você pode ter:

```
$minha_variavel = $se_aqui_for_verdadeiro ? $isso : $se_nao_isso;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Kenny Rafael

Comment: De nada @SrWeb, considere marcar a resposta como correta caso tenha ajudado! =)

Comment: Está marcada meu amigo, desculpa a demora, por incrível que pareça fiquei quase 1 mês sem precisar vir no fórum, isso é bom não é? KKKK Sinal que as coisas iam bem, valeu

Comment: hahahha issoa ai, precisando!!!